# What is the best solution to make a jQuery Character Cycle Plugin Unobtrusive?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-selectors, unobtrusive-javascript

I created a little jQuery plugin to create a character cycling effect on some event, much like the effect on [yugop.com](http://www.yugop.com/). I would like to separate the element whose event triggers the cycling from the element but I can't figure out how to do this without using unique ids. The best I have right is to have the element whose text is being cycled as a child of the element triggering the cycling. and select it based on an id.

Here is the [demo](http://robincwillis.com/_test/charCycle/)

Here is how the plugin is called

```
$('.c').mouseenter(function(){
    if($(this).hasClass('cycling')==false){ 
                $(this).charcycle({'target':'#text'});  
    }
});
```

Here is the html markup for the elements being manipulated

```
<div class="c">
   <a href="#" id="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit</a>  
</div>
```

mousing over the div is triggering the plugin which is cycling text in the element with the id "text" which is specified when calling the plugin.

Here are the jQuery selectors I am using within the plugin

```
settings.targetElement=$(this).find(settings.target);
settings.quoteStr=settings.targetElement.text();
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Show us your code! I don't get what you're talking about otherwise...

Comment: Sorry I included the code I think is relavent to the question, and you can view the full source on the demo.

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like:

```
$(this).charcycle({'target': $(this).contents(":first-child") });
```

But probably more practically, you would use this as a default fall-back position, in the absence of being passed an explicit target.

Comment: I prefer specifying the elements id to this solution because this demands that the target element is in fact the first child which is less flexible. I am more interested to know if there was a way to keep the scripts functionality without the two elements having a child parent relationship, or any strict relationship at all with out having using unique ids?

Answer (score 0):

You could use additional classes on hovered element to specify elements of what class to trigger the cycling on. Something like this might work:

```
$('.c').mouseenter(function(){
    if (!$(this).hasClass('cycling'))
    { 
        var prefix = 'ctarget-';
        var classes = $(this).attr('class').split(' ');
        // enumerate all the classes of this element
        for (var i in classes)
        {
            // if a class starts with a known prefix (see above)
            if (classes[i].substr(0, prefix.length) == prefix)
            {
                // then extract target class from it and use that
                $(this).charcycle({target: '.'+classes[i].substr(prefix.length)});
            }
        }
    }
});
```

The HTML would look like this:

```
<div class="c ctarget-text1">trigger</div>
<a href="#" class="text1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</a>
```

(By the way: not a good thing to use multiple elements with the same id, you should have probably used classes there instead.)